# Android app not obeying Universal Link URL path prefix specifed in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have a React Native app which uses universal links.

No matter what `pathPrefix` I specify, it will only launch the app on links that look like `https://www.companyname.com/callback/something`

With my current config below, I expect it not to launch on `..../callback/...` but with links like `https://www.companyname.com/123callback/something`.

How can it be that it seems to be stuck with `/callback`?

I've cleaned the `android/app/build` and ran `./gradlw clean` etc before rebuilding. I also tried wiping data of the emulator. No luck.

This is how my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` looks

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.companyname.mobileapp">

    <application
            ....
        <activity
                .....>
.....
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.companyname.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/123callback/"
                />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I needed to enable the supported web addresses in the app setttings.

The reason why `/callback` was still working without this, was because the website had made https://www.companyname.com/callback/* redirect to `myapp://callback/*`...